# Plotting only one piece of an implicit 3d surface (the one value of the order parameter wich minimizes some free energy function)

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, discontinuity

I would like to plot a graphic of spontaneous magnetization vs `T` vs `h` for a Curie Weiss Model. The equation for stationary points is `Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m = 0`, so I used ContourPlot3d to plot the surface as follows

```
ContourPlot3D[Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0, {m, -1.5, 1.5}, {T, 0, 3}, {h, -2, 2}]
```

This is something more than what I would have seen, because there can be more than one stationary point and I have to select the one which minimizes the "m-dependent free energy"

```
F[m,h,T]=-m^2/2 - m*h + T*(((1 + m)/2)*Log[(1 + m)/2] + ((1 - m)/2)*Log[(1 - m)/2])
```

I can't find a way to ask mathematica to plot only the piece with m giving the lowest `F[m,h,T]` and you would really help me if you could explain me how to do such thing. I would like to have a discontinuous surface like the one in the picture.

I also tried to make that in this other way

```
ContourPlot3D[F[m, h, T] == MinValue[F[m, h, T], m], {m, -1.5, 1.5}, {T, 0,3}, {h, -2, 2}]
```

but what happened is that Mathematica started running without ever ending, and maybe is simpler to fix the first one try.

Thank you very much

[image: example of what I would like to plot, with a discontinuity for h=0, T<1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second order conditions for the solution to `Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0` to give a minimum for `F[m, h, T]` is simple:

```
soc = D[F[m, h, T], {m, 2}] > 0 // FullSimplify
```

> (-1 + m^2) (-1 + m^2 + T) < 0

Taking into account the domain restrictions on `h`, `m` and `T`

```
dom = -1 <= m <= 1 && -2 <= h <= 2 && 0 <= T <= 3;
Reduce[soc && dom, T]
-2 <= h <= 2 && -1 < m < 1 && 1 - m^2 < T <= 3
```

So, we can take `soc = 1 - m^2 < T <= 3`.

We can use `soc` and/or `D[F[m, h, T], {m, 2}]`  with `ContourPlot3D` in a number of ways to get the desired surface:

***RegionFunction***

```
ContourPlot3D[Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0, {m, -1, 1}, {h, -2, 2}, {T, 0, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{m, h, T}, soc]]
```

[image]

***ColorFunction***

```
ContourPlot3D[Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0, {m, -1, 1}, {h, -2, 2}, {T, 0, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{m, h, T}, If[soc, Red, White]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

***MeshFunctions***

Yet another approach is to use the second derivative of `F` wrt `m` as the setting for the option `MeshFunctions`:

```
ContourPlot3D[Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0, {m, -1, 1}, {h, -2, 2}, {T, 0, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{m, h, T}, (-1 + m^2) (-1 + m^2 + T)]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, White}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

***SliceContourPlot3D***

Alternatively, we can use [`SliceContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) with the second derivative of `F` wrt `m` as the first argument and first-order condition as the second argument:

```
D[F[m, h, T], {m, 2}] // FullSimplify
```

> (-1 + m^2 + T)/(-1 + m^2)

```
SliceContourPlot3D[(-1 + m^2 + T)/(-1 + m^2), 
 Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0, {m, -1, 1}, {h, -2, 2}, {T, 0, 3}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> { White, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: This condition works fine in delating the piece of surface associated with the instable maximum in the m dependent free energy, but I would like to erase also the metastable minimum. Nevertheless, your answer is quite useful, I really liked the first one. I also would like to ask you, if you know, why is there a wedge of low temperature and negative h which is erased from the surface? (not an important question this last one)

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution, but perhaps a small step forward:

You might color the surface depending on `F[m,h,T]`.

```
ContourPlot3D[Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0, {m, -1 , 1 }, {h, -2, 2}, {T, 0, 3},ColorFunctionScaling -> ! True
,ColorFunction ->Function[{m, h, T }, Hue[F[m, h, T ]]] ,  ColorFunctionScaling ->  True, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**outlook for an answer**

My idea to solve your problem:

First calculate the minimum of F depending on `h,T`

```
minF[h_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] :=MinValue[{F[m, h, T], -.99 < m < .99}, m]
```

Second combine the two conditions inside `ContourPlot3D`

```
ContourPlot3D[Tanh[(m + h)/T] - m == 0&& m==minF[h,T], {h, -2, 2}
, {T, 0, 3}, {m, -1 , 1 }, 
ColorFunctionScaling ->  True,ColorFunction -> Function[{m, h, T }, Hue[F[m, h, T ]]] ,AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Unfortunately Mathematica v12 can't evaluate the last step ...